# Working with related collections in Bookshelf JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

Having issues using Bookshelf Collections, and not finding answers in the [API level documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/), which does a poor job of illustrating how to tie the pieces together.

Using the following setup for Bookshelf, including the model registry plugin:

```
const knexConfig = require('../knexfile')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
const knex       = require('knex')(knexConfig);
const bookshelf  = require('bookshelf')(knex);

bookshelf.plugin('registry');
```

Suppose that the following models exist:

```
const Foo = bookshelf.model('Foo', {
  tableName: 'foos',
  bars: function() { return this.hasMany('Bar'); }
});

const Bar = bookshelf.model('Bar', {
  tableName: 'bars',
  foo: function() { return this.belongsTo('Foo'); }
});
```

We have some bulk operation we wish to execute on an entire collection of `Bar` objects. Rather than iterate through each `Bar`, we wish to reduce it to a single query. So we create a collection of `Bars`:

```
const Bars = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: 'Bar',
  bulkOperation: function() {
    // contrived example
    return this.query.save({field: 'value'});
  }
});
```

When it comes to actually running the bulk operation for a given `Foo`'s `Bars`, we find that `bars.bulkOperation()` is not a `Bars` `Collection`, but simply a `CollectionBase`.

```
Foo
  .where({id: 1})
  .fetch({withRelated: 'bars'})
  .then(foo => foo.related('bars'))
  .then(bars => bars.bulkOperation()); // bars.bulkOperation is not a function
```

Obviously, `CollectionBase` doesn't have `bulkOperation` defined on it.

**How do we get a `Bars` `Collection` from the `related('bars')`, such that we can run out bulk operation?**

Comment: Oh, this thing that is called "bookshelf" is one of terrible ORMs that I have ever used. So unpredictable. Buggy. Poor documentations...

Comment: @Vohuman, do you know a better alternative?

Comment: I have mostly used PHP for developing server-side applications (I had to), Laravel's Eloquent is a good ORM. In node, I have used Sequalize and bookshelf. Sequalize is better in my opinion but it also suffers from the same problems as bookshelf. I use an ORM that I have written myself (a small ES6 class that uses knex) and it does what _I_ expect an ORM should do, at least I know what happens in my queries. As a suggestion do your _specific/complex queries_  by creating helper functions. Promises and other JavaScript features make this pretty  easy. Don't waste your time on fixing ORM issues.

Comment: @bosticko I know this is 4years later, but did you ever resolve this?